# When is OLS estimation bias due to endogeneity negligible?

Tags: econometrics, least-squares, endogeneity, hausman

I have a question about OLS estimation bias due to endogeneity. Say I have the following panel regression model for the price of good 1 for a particular sale $k$ at time $t$:

$$P_{kt}^1=\beta M_{t} + \varepsilon_{kt}$$

The price is a function of the market share of a substitute, good 2, and is a function of quantity and price for each good summed overall all sales:

$$M_t=\frac{\sum_jP_{jt}^2Q_{jt}^2}{\sum_iP_{it}^1Q_{it}^1+\sum_jP_{jt}^2Q_{jt}^2}$$

Clearly, $M_i$ is endogenous, but I'd like to know whether or not the endogeneity is significant enough to be concerned about. Let's say that $i=1,...,N$ and $j=1,...,M$. As $N$ or $M$ grows very large, does the bias due to endogeneity become negligible? If so, how can I show this? I haven't made much progress on the problem; basically I get this far and I'm not sure what to do next:

$$E(M_t\varepsilon_{kt})=\sum_jP_{jt}^2Q_{jt}^2\frac{\varepsilon_{kt} }{\sum_{i\neq k}P_{it}^1Q_{it}^1+\sum_{j}P_j^2Q_j^2+Q_k^1(\beta M_t + \varepsilon_{kt})}$$

Empirically, I tried using a Durbin-Wu-Hausman test for endogeneity, but this led to problems of it's own (when I conducted the augmented regression, some of the "exogenous" variables were dropped due to multicollinearity). That's why I'm trying to address the question analytically.

Comment: Generally, bias isn't diminished by increasing N, eg, the amount of endogeneity will be a function of the degree to which the included variables are correlated w/ omitted variables that have a causal relationship w/ the response.